# Query GSuite Directory API with a Google Cloud Platform service account

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-workspace

I want to query [GSuite Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) to return all users in a group, in Go, and **authenticated as a GCP service account** (the script will be executed in a Google Compute Engine VM or as a Google Cloud Function).

The service account I use (let's call it `my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) have been granted necessary scopes in GSuite :

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group

At my disposal, I also have a GSuite **Admin** account (let's call it `my-admin@my-domain.com`). This account will be used for **delegation** (see [the docs on delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object)).

I am able to return all users in a group with the following code (based on the code in the link provided above, and I have removed most of error handling to make the code shorter) :

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    admin "google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1"
)

func main() {
    srv := createAdminDirectoryService(
        os.Getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH"),
        os.Getenv("GSUITE_ADMIN_USER_EMAIL"),
    )
    members := listUsersInGroup(srv, os.Args[1])
    log.Println(members)
}

func createAdminDirectoryService(serviceAccountFilePath,
                                 gsuiteAdminUserEmail string) *admin.Service {
    jsonCredentials, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(serviceAccountFilePath)

    config, _ := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(
        jsonCredentials,
        admin.AdminDirectoryGroupMemberReadonlyScope,
    )
    config.Subject = gsuiteAdminUserEmail

    ctx := context.Background()
    client := config.Client(ctx)

    srv, _ := admin.New(client)
    return srv
}

func listUsersInGroup(srv *admin.Service, groupEmail string) []string {
    members, err := srv.Members.List(groupEmail).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    membersEmails := make([]string, len(members.Members))
    for i, member := range members.Members {
        membersEmails[i] = member.Email
    }

    return membersEmails
}
```

As you can see, that code **requires to have a JSON key file** of `my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. This is the only way I have found to create a `jwt.Config` object.

Moreover, note that delegation is done with the line `config.Subject = gsuiteAdminUserEmail`; without that, I got the error :

```
googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes., insufficientPermissions
```

Anyway, running :

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH=/path/to/json/key/of/my/service/account \
GSUITE_ADMIN_USER_EMAIL=my-admin@my-domain.com \
go run main.go my-group@my-domain.com
```

prints with success all users in `my-group@my-domain.com`.

**However**, since this code will be run from a Google Compute Engine VM (or a Google Cloud Function) with `my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com` used as service account, it seems ridiculous to need a JSON key of that service account to authenticate (since I am already authenticated as `my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, on the VM or inside the GCF).

I have tried to replace the content of `createAdminDirectoryService()` with the following code to authenticate as the user who launched the script (with default credentials) :

```
func createAdminDirectoryService() *admin.Service {
    ctx := context.Background()

    client, _ := google.DefaultClient(ctx, scopes...)

    srv, _ := admin.New(client)
    return srv
}
```

But listing users returns an error :

```
googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes., insufficientPermissions
```

As this is the same error I have got when I removed the delegation, I think this is related. Indeed, I did not provide my GSuite Admin account anywhere during the `admin.Service` creation.

Can anyone help about one of these points :

- How can I authenticate directly with the user running the go script on a Google Compute Engine VM, or a Google Cloud Function?
- Do I really need a JSON key file to generate a `jwt.Config` object?
- I have looked into the source code of `golang.org/x/oauth2/google`, I could get a `oauth2.Config` instead of `jwt.Config`, but it does not seem possible to "delegate" with a oauth2 token. How else can I perform the delegation?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: @anantary Unfortunately no, I've just embedded the content of the service account key (JSON string) as an environment variable of my Cloud Function. I've used Google KMS to encrypt the JSON string though to avoid viewers seeing the unencrypted JSON string in the *environment variables* section.

Answer (score 0):

This post is somewhat old, but hope this can help:

I had the same problem and made it work by changing the OAuth scopes in the Compute Instance (by default, the scopes only include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`). In my case, I had to add the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly` scope. It can be done using the `gcloud compute instances set-service-account` command. That way the service account bearer token received from the metadata server has the correct scopes to access the Admin Directory API.

Unfortunately, it cannot be done for Cloud Functions as the Cloud Functions OAuth scopes do not seem to be customizable.

See [this post](https://www.0x6.eu/2021/06/adc-access-googleapis.html) for more details.

Btw it is also possible now to give a service account access to the Admin Directory API [without domain-wide delegation](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/setup#auth-no-dwd).

Answer (score -1):

```golang
    r, err := srv.Users.List().
        ViewType("domain_public").
        Customer("my_customer").
        OrderBy("email").
        Do()
```

Try using this.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack overflow! Consider adding a bit more detail about _why_ your answer will work or where the question asker was not on the right track.